# Build Windows driver with C99 ANSI standard

Tags: c, c99, c89, wdk, cl.exe

I have a WDK windows driver written in C, and I use WinDDK build.exe utility to build it. The problem is build.exe utility uses visual studio cl.exe compiler, which compiles files with *.c according to C89 standard. According to this standard, all block-level variables must be declared at the beginning of the block. In my driver, I have a huge file that breaks this convention and I would not like to change it. Therefore, I need to compile the driver with C99 convention.

According to the list of options, cl.exe does not allow to specify a standard: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwkeyyhe.aspx .

Also note, that this is not a visual studio project and I can`t use gcc, because I use WinDDK.

Comment: Have you looked if there are converters from C99 to ANSI C? If mixed declarations are the only used C99 feature, then the change should be trivial.

Comment: I don't know if anything changed, but Visual Studio never supported C99 and they were never going to support C99.

Comment: Even if you don't use Visual Studio, you still have it installed to get the compiler. Have you thought about upgrading it to a later version? Because lately Microsoft have been adding a lot of C99 into its C compiler.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have VS2013, will the upgrade to VS2015 
help? Also, my teammate can`t upgrade, so it will be a partial solution.

Comment: If you have VS2013 then it should already support C99 variable declarations. See e.g. [this Microsoft blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/06/28/c-11-14-stl-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-vs-2013.aspx).

Comment: So I have checked it and yeah, they add c99 library compliance in VS2015, but no language features.

Comment: Visual Studio is mainly a C++ compiler, it has never followed _any_ version of the C standard very well. VS is notorious for this: if standard compliance or quality are concerns, you need to port the whole project.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be they have some c99 support since VS2013 but not only library support as for example compound literals and, designated initializers have been added.

Comment: WDK up to about version 7.1.0 (7600.16385.1) or so includes its own compiler, but later versions of the WDK integrate into Visual Studio and presumably use the compiler included with Visual C++? I don't know though, as I prefer to stick to the older versions of WDK with its command-line build system.